# Macroing with auto-hotkey image search

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I am using a function to detect if a tree is ready to harvest or if it has been depleted. (They deplete over time, not after being harvested) I would like to keep my macro doing other things, so I don't want to have it go through the process of planting a tree when it is not needed, even though that is a valid fix. The problem reside's in the depleted trees, it refuses to recognize any image I create of them. Here is my code:

```
    treeCheck() 

{

  global img_treeHarvest 

  WinGetPos, , , windowSizeX, windowSizeY , A

  ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_treeHarvest%

  if (ErrorLevel = 0) {

    MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY

    MouseMove, myszX + 15, myszY + 2

    Sleep, 25

    MouseClick

    Sleep, 25

    MouseMove, mouseX, mouseY

    Sleep, 10

  }
  else {

     ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_farmready%

     if (ErrorLevel = 0) {

        MouseMove, 716, 197

      Pause
     }
   }
 }
```

Here are the images I am using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olrIl.jpg
I think the problem is that the depleted version is transparent

Comment: you should edit your question to include the actual question you want answered.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I've been coding for wayy too long

Comment: If you've fixed your problem, please post an answer and say what you did instead of deleting everything from the question.

Comment: @DennisMeng - Question clearly abandoned with no intent to post the found solution. I've voted for close as unclear what you are asking, so that no one wastes time with this.